# How can I stringify and destringify a Function in Dart?

Tags: function, dart

Basically, I need to store a Function and fetch the same Function using a file. jsonEncode/Decode doesn't work (because stringification fails) and I can't find any other way to do this. The Function class doesn't have a parameters/body getter, so I don't even know how to implement my own logic.

```dart
functionEncode(Function x);
functionDecode(Function x); // How do I implement these?

Function x = (int x) {return x * 2;};

void main() {
   String encoded = functionEncode(x);
   Function decoded = functionDecode(x);
   assert(decoded == x); //passes
}
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to stringify/destringify a Function? Is this even possible?

Comment: Interesting question. So can I assume you are trying to create functions at runtime? Or are these functions existing in your codebase already?

Comment: Not possible. If you want to dynamically load Dart code on runtime, you need to use `Isolate.spawnUri` which spawn a `Isolate` running the code, which will run (as the name imply) isolated from the rest of you code and can only communicate by using message passing.

Comment: @dumazy I'm creating a task-scheduling library. I need to persist the tasks. So functions are provided by a user, and I'm trying to find a way to get them into and out of a File.

Comment: @AKushWarrior, so the user are expected to write Dart code and send to your service? I guess it would make sense to run the code for each job as independent `Isolate` instances (or just spawn a Dart VM for each job running) since these jobs are not expected to interact with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is essentially the ability to run arbitrary code (in the form of stringified functions) during runtime. This is technically possible to do, but it's a roundabout way, and is demonstrated in an article on iiro.dev:

```dart
final code = 'void main() { print("Hello World"); }';
final uri = Uri.dataFromString(code, mimeType: 'application/dart');
await Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [], null);
```

(The full article can be found [here](https://iiro.dev/2019/08/15/how-to-eval-in-dart/).)

There are several caveats to doing this, however. First, it only works when your program is running in JIT mode, so if you compile your Dart program into an AOT-compiled stand-alone program, it just plain will not work. (In Flutter, this means it only works when the app is running in debug mode rather than release mode.)

Second, running this code falls under the same umbrella as using `eval` in Javascript, in that it is not only error-prone but is also a *h u g e* security risk. If you put this code in an app and publish the app, you are essentially installing a backdoor into people's phones that allows someone to run any code they want. There is no real way to restrict or sandbox this feature, so it will always be a security concern to such an extent that your app will always house the possibility of becoming trojan-horse malware.

So basically, the answer to your question is the same as if someone were asking how to use `eval`. And the answer is always the same: ***YOU DON'T***.

Comment: This is what I needed. I'll be rethinking my architecture. Thanks...